# Can I have a Interface in method?

Tags: java

I know that that on can have a class declaration in a method of class.
Eg. We can have anonymous class declaration for event handling in a method body.

But I want to know that same way can I have Interface declaration in a method in a class.

What is use of that?

Comment: After reading fastcodejava's post, I think I misunderstood the OP. Do you mean inner/anonymous-interface within a method?

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' assuming you are refering to returning an interface for a method?

Short answer: Yes.

Why?

Here's a good post.
[Why we return type Mostly Interface rather than Class?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/408971/Beginning-Java/java/Why-we-return-type-Mostly)

Excerpt:

> The benefit is that returning an
>   interface makes it possible to change
>   the implementation later on. E.g., you
>   might decide after a while that you'd
>   much rather use a LinkedList instead
>   of an ArrayList.....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can declare an Interface inside a method. Why would you want to?
You can only define an anonymous inner class.

Comment: nested interfaces are implicitly static and cannot be defined in a method body.

Answer (score 1):

No. why don't you just write one, compile, and see for yourself?

Suppose an interface can be declared inside a method, it wouldn't be accessible outside. It's hard to imagine the usefulness of such an interface confined in a block. A local class on the other hand can be useful since it contains concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, a well known example is the [`Comparator<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparator.html) interface.

For example:

```
List<Person> persons = personDAO.list();

Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() { 
    // Anonymous inner class which implements Comparator interface.
    public int compare(Person one, Person other) {
        return one.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
    }
});
```

Some may argue against this and tell that it rather belongs in the `Person` class, so that you don't need to implement it again and again whenever needed. E.g.

```
public class Person {

    // ...

    public static final Comparator<Person> ORDER_BY_NAME = new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person one, Person other) {
            return one.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
        }
    };
}
```

which can be used as follows:

```
Collections.sort(persons, Person.ORDER_BY_NAME);
```

Comment: I think what you have in your example is an anonymous class which is an instance of the interface Comparator. But I think the OP's question was whether an interface declaration can exist inside a method, which is not possible in Java. Or is it I miss something here ?

Comment: Hmm this doesn't make any sense. But I think you're right that it was actually his question. I'd be curious where he wanted to use it for. To get better answers he at least need to edit his question with a concrete example of what he's trying to achieve.